# Closure properties of a non-regular language under complement?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, pumping-lemma

- Assume I have L1 which is a regular language, so we know since regular language is closed under complement, the complement of L1 is also a regular language.
- But let's say if the complement of L1 is a non-regular language, is it safe to conclude that L1 is a non-regular language as well?

Since I'm trying to prove a language L1 is not a regular language, and the pumping lemma doesn't work well with this case. But I can easily prove the complement of L1 is not regular, I'm wonder if that option is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, non-regular languages are closed under complement as well.

Suppose the complement of L1 is a non-regular language. If L1 is regular, then "the complement of L1 is also a regular language", which is not true. Hence L1 cannot be regular.

More generally, suppose we have defined a collection of languages as myLanguages. Then

myLanguages are closed under complement $\Longleftrightarrow$ non-myLanguages are closed under complement

For example, we have

- non-context-free languages are not closed under complement.
- non-context-sensitive languages are closed under complement.
- non-deterministic-context-free languages are closed under complement.